# Why can't keyboards be used in customized linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, keyboard, kernel-parameters

I am customizing a Linux system using a Linux kernel of 6.4.0. After booting, why is the keyboard not working? # 1. The disk is externally connected through a USB interface. If I enter the Linux live environment, the keyboard can be used.
I compiled the keyboard driver and USB interface driver into the kernel, such as # 2 and # 3.

#1
[image]

#2
[image]

#3
[image]

reply **Spacerat**：

[image]

add keyboard menu:
[image]

Comment: I made a mistake. I thought the CONFIG option was m and there was no need to do anything else to make the driver work. In fact, only when the CONFIG option was y can the driver be compiled into the kernel and used directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using gentoo (?)

anyway, check: CONFIG_USB_* (like for example: CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD=y for USB3) in your kernel config.

Comment: As shown in the screenshot just added above, USB has always been supported.

Answer (score 1):

These two options you selected are sub-menus. Selecting "Keyboard support" just enables the menu where you can select which keyboards will be supported (having this as an option is convenient when using the non-graphical config system). You can see this in the option's help text. Press the enter key on this option, to enter the keyboard support menu.

Selecting "USB support" does enable the USB core in the kernel, but you also need to go into the sub-menu and make sure you select the drivers for the kinds of USB chips and USB devices you want the kernel to support.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe it clearly. The driver settings for the keyboard and USB are default to the kernel, and I have not modified them. My keyboard should be a universal version.